# Is there a way to achieve high throughput in gRPC?

Tags: c++, grpc, throughput

I'm working on gRPC(C++), where client send request to server for only once, and server streams back sorted messages to client. I get stuck on gRPC performance for several weeks, mainly on the throughput.

According to the discussion(https://www.mail-archive.com/grpc-io@googlegroups.com/msg07220.html), we know gRPC only allows one message outstanding, which means it's hard to fully utilize b/w. And that's exactly the phenomenon I've observed on wireshark.

The method I could think out:

1.batching. I've implemented a batchpool, which only sends out messages(`stream->Write(msg)`) when batched message size is over my preset threshold. I tune it as 50MB, and it gains some improvement.

Why I don't use `set_buffer_hint`? It blocks my thread.
See issue here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12975

2.use multiple connection to maximize bandwidth and receiver's buffer.
Since my messages are sorted, and client is supposed to handle sorted messages. I assume there would be synchronization issue here.

Also, I've tried gRPC provided

```
  grpc::ChannelArguments args;
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_STREAM_LOOKAHEAD_BYTES,
              1024 * 1024 * 1024 /* 1GB */);
  args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS, 50);
```

I don't observe obvious improvement.

3.Ostrich algorithm. Deploy my service on a local data-center. With lower latency, low bytes-in-flight is not that important.

Some stats for my service:

my service deployed at pod ~10MBps, QoS of Guarenteed(limits/requested both 10CPU/32GB)

I'm wondering: is there a way to improve throughput really in gRPC?

Comment: `is there a way to improve throughput really in gRPC` Probably not. Why would you want to use gRPC instead of plain old messages?

Comment: What do you mean by "plain old message"? Well, I would add some context: the message I send is (de)serialized in protobuf, which is compatible with gRPC. As for why gRPC? The main reason is: my mentor's existing codebase does so.

Comment: Existing codebase is a rock-solid argument. But I found gRPC quite inadequate to the task of fast messaging. You can send proto messages via network.

Comment: "send proto messages via network", you mean send it via another network communication framework?

Comment: Or just use plain socket API.

Comment: Oh you really surprised me